how do I use a 3-vector function in numpy?
As this question regards a university project, I don't think I am allowed to share my full code without it counting as cheating, but regardless:
In my code I must call a function:
f = lambda t,y: np.array([y[0] - 2*y[1] + t*y[2], - y[0] + y[1] + y[2] - t*t, t*y[1] - y[1] + t*t*t])

with the idea being that I use these functions to calculate results for a (3,n) array, where the first row of results is calculated using the first function in f and so on. The issue comes from how to call each specific function.
I have tried using f[0](t,y) (in reference to the first function of the array f, for example) but this has resulted in a
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable.
The expected result is that f[0](t,y) would use the function in the index [0] of f when calculating.

If you can't share the full code, write a snippet of code that causes the same exception when ran. We need to know at least the shape of y (assuming it's a NumPy array),the type of t and how you're calling f.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You define ONE function, not 3:
In [351]: f = lambda t,y: np.array([y[0] - 2*y[1] + t*y[2], - y[0] + y[1] + y[2] - t*t, t*y[1] - y[1] + t*t*t])

When asking a question, you should provide a simple example, for example:
In [358]: y = np.random.randint(1,5,(3,4)); y
Out[358]: 
array([[1, 3, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 4, 1],
       [3, 3, 1, 4]])

In [359]: res = f(2,y)

In [360]: res
Out[360]: 
array([[ 5,  5, -5,  7],
       [-1, -2,  0,  0],
       [ 9, 10, 12,  9]])

In [361]: res[0]
Out[361]: array([ 5,  5, -5,  7])

Calling f returns a 3 row array.  You can reference one row.  But you can't index f itself:
In [362]: f[0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[362], line 1
----> 1 f[0]

TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

You could define a list of 3 functions:
In [363]: f = [lambda t,y: y[0] - 2*y[1] + t*y[2], lambda t,y: - y[0] + y[1] + y[2] - t*t, lambda t,y: t*y[1] - y[1] + t*t*t]

In [364]: f
Out[364]: 
[<function __main__.<lambda>(t, y)>,
 <function __main__.<lambda>(t, y)>,
 <function __main__.<lambda>(t, y)>]

In [366]: f[0](2,y)
Out[366]: array([ 5,  5, -5,  7])

Perhaps this would be clearer if we wrote your function with regular def syntax.  lambda is just a 'shorthand'; it doesn't change the nature of the function.
In [368]: def f(t,y): 
     ...:     res = np.array([y[0] - 2*y[1] + t*y[2], 
     ...:                   - y[0] + y[1] + y[2] - t*t, 
     ...:                     t*y[1] - y[1] + t*t*t])
     ...:     return res
     ...:     

In [369]: f(2,y)
Out[369]: 
array([[ 5,  5, -5,  7],
       [-1, -2,  0,  0],
       [ 9, 10, 12,  9]])

